# PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC on Android : number of iterations for keygeneration and cipher?

Tags: java, android, security, aes, pbkdf2

I'm using PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC with BouncyCastle.

```
public static String algorithm = "PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC";
```

I've done this method to generate the secret key:

```
private void generateSK(char[] passPhrase, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException {
    pbeParamSpecKey = new PBEParameterSpec(salt,1000);
    PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase);
    SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory;

    secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
    secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
}
```

and then this to generate a Cipher object (for encryption or decryption):

```
protected Cipher getCipher(int mode) {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        cipher.init(mode, secretKey, pbeParamSpecKey);

        return cipher;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The pbeParamSpecKey need to be the same? How much is "important" (in terms of security) the number of iterations generating the key and the one generating the Cipher object? Can they be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The pbeParamSpecKey need to be the same? How much is "important" (in terms of security) the number of iterations generating the key and the one generating the Cipher object?

This is a hard question that you need to answer yourself. The general guidance is, as large as possible without annoying the user too much, but 1000 iterations is a bit low nowadays.

The next thing you need to do is try to benchmark your application on different devices that your user group probably has. Then you can fine-tune accordingly.

Maybe you can slightly redesign your app so that the key derivation happens in the background during idle phases and can therefore take a longer time. Though, this may introduce other problems like keeping the derived key safe and not leakable.

> Can they be different?

AES is a symmetric block cipher and as such needs the *same* key for encryption and decryption. To generate the *same* key, you need to use the *same* password, salt and number of iterations for PBKDF2.

Comment: thanks.
I'll apply your suggestion for key generation in background.
There's still one thing I don't understand. When I init the cipher I pass both the secretkey (generated before) AND the PBEKeySpec, but you say that it uses this last param to generate the key.

How the code to init the cipher with an already generated secretkey should be?

I've tried simply with:

cipher.init(mode, secretKey);

but it also generates an IV each time (if I pass the params, IV is generated by them) and I'd avoid to store another value (the IV) for each encrypted data.

Comment: I haven't used BouncyCastle, so I don't know if you actually need to init the cipher object with `pbeParamSpecKey`. Maybe you can try to keep only the first two parameters to that call and see if anything changes.

Comment: I did it with SecretKeySpec and now it works as I wanted! I use a lot of iterations (100000) for the key generation, and then the cipher.init is very quick. Of course I'll do the first step in background! thank your very much!